# Change element content and color when a button is clicked - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've tried to switch by boolean but for some reason it won't work.

```
function onBall3Click() {
    var ball3 = document.querySelector('.ball3')
    
    var isOn = true; 
    
    if ( isOn )
    {
       ball3.style.backgroundColor = 'Yellow'
       ball3.innerText = 'ON'
    }
    else
    {
       ball3.style.backgroundColor = 'Grey'
       ball3.innerText = 'OFF'   
    }
    
    isOn = !isOn
    
    ball3.style.width = ball3Size + 'px';
    ball3.style.height = ball3Size + 'px';
}
```

I put a boolean with `if` and `else` and expected the colors and text to change.

Comment: You always set it to true when you call the function.

Comment: everytime you call your function. you hardcoded your variable to be true `var isOn = true;` so it will always be true on function call

Comment: write `var isOn = true;` outside function

Answer (score 1):

There is no possible scenario in which this condition would ever be `false`:

```
var isOn = true;
if ( isOn ){
```

The variable is *explicitly defined* as `true` and then immediately tested to see if it's `true`.  Which it will be.

It sounds like you want the scope of the variable to be *outside* the function.  For example:

```
var isOn = true;

function onBall3Click() {
  var ball3 = document.querySelector('.ball3');
  if (isOn) {
    ball3.style.backgroundColor = 'Yellow';
    ball3.innerText = 'ON';
  } else {
    ball3.style.backgroundColor = 'Grey';
    ball3.innerText = 'OFF';
  }
  isOn = !isOn;
  ball3.style.width = ball3Size + 'px';
  ball3.style.height = ball3Size + 'px';
}
```

This way the variable is only defined once, and the same instance of the variable is used each time the function is invoked.  Which will allow the current value of the variable to persist after the function completes and be read again the next time the function is called.

Comment: thx David, helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should use data attributes to handle state-keeping.

Here is an example of a global click listener that checks if the element that you clicked is a ball. If it is a ball, toggle the state of the data attribute using the `dataset` property.

The CSS will now control the look of the ball.

```js
// Could be modified to handle non-binary states
const getNextState = (state) => {
  switch (state) {
    case 'on':
      return 'off';
    case 'off':
    default:
      return 'on';
  }
};

const toggleState = (ball) => {
  const currentState = ball.dataset.state ?? 'off';
  ball.dataset.state = getNextState(currentState);
}

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('ball')) {
    toggleState(e.target);
  }
});
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body {
  display: flex; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center;
  background: #222;
}

.ball {
  aspect-ratio: 1; /* Keep width/height a ratio of 1/1 */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: grey;
  width: 1rem;
  width: attr(data-size rem); /* Experimental */
}

/* Hard-coded rules */
.ball[data-size="2"] { width: 2rem; }
.ball[data-size="3"] { width: 3rem; }
.ball[data-size="4"] { width: 4rem; }

.ball:hover { cursor: pointer; }

.ball[data-state="on"] { background: yellow; }
.ball[data-state="off"] { background: grey; }
```

```html
<div class="ball" data-size="2"></div>
<div class="ball" data-size="4"></div>
<div class="ball" data-size="3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `if/else` statement as follows:

```js
if (ball3.style.backgroundColor == 'Yellow') {
  // was on
} else {
  //was off
}
```

Comment: Don't use the DOM to store state, except with data attributes.